# Config value interpolation using Circle CI?

Tags: c#, circleci

I am attempting to interpolate API username and password into my appsettings.json using Circle CI. I have placeholder values "ApiUsernamePlaceholder" and "ApiPasswordPlaceholder" that correspond to "Username" and "Password" fields in the json, like so:

```
"API": {
    "URL": "https://some.url.com/api",
    "username": "ApiUsernamePlaceholder",
    "password": "ApiPasswordPlaceholder"
}
```

Is it possible, using Circle CI, to substitute the placeholders with an actual value at runtime? I have found conflicting statements on the issue, and the documentation is not clear.
This is a .Net Core 2.0 C# API project.

Comment: Any reference for "I have found conflicting statements on the issue"?

Comment: shouldn't you be reading the values from the appsettings.json and not setting the values i.e. the placeholders you have would contain the actual values you need?

Comment: @David that is the issue, I am looking for a way to swap out the "placeholder" string for the actual value so that when I read from the config, the appropriate values are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Like on any Unix-based environment, during your build use `sed` to swap out the place holders for the value of private environment variables that you'd set via the CircleCI webapp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did get the sed command working. Is accessing Circle Webapp environment variables the same as accessing ones defined in the config.yml? If i have one defined from the UI as API_PASSWORD, I just reference it as $API_PASSWORD in the config.yml?

Comment: Yes it is the same.

Comment: A few days late, but this helped my understanding. Thanks!